# iTouch, 5th Gen., Rear-Facing Camera

Tags: multi-touch

Is there any way to remove the screen that is blocking the rear facing camera? Could I bring it into a store and pay to have it removed/a camera put in?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. No authorized service personnel will do so even if paid. There is the good chance the device itself might not work if it finds to rear camera missing.